# Operations on numpy masked array gives invalid values masked

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, missing-data, masked-array

From the documentation on masked arrays in numpy [operations on numpy arrays](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html#operations-on-masked-arrays):

> The numpy.ma module comes with a specific implementation of most ufuncs. Unary and binary functions that have a validity domain (such as log or divide) return the masked constant whenever the input is masked or falls outside the validity domain: e.g.:

```
ma.log([-1, 0, 1, 2])
masked_array(data = [-- -- 0.0 0.69314718056],
             mask = [ True  True False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

I have the problem that for my calculations I need to know where those invalid operations were produced. Concretely I would like this instead:

```
ma.log([-1, 0, 1, 2])
masked_array(data = [np.nan -- 0.0 0.69314718056],
             mask = [ True  True False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

At the risk of this question being conversational my main question is:

What is a good solution to get this `masked_array` where the computed invalid values (those "fixed" by [`fix_invalid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.fix_invalid.html#numpy.ma.fix_invalid), like np.nan and np.inf) are not turned into (and conflated with) masked values?

My current solution would be to compute the function on the `masked_array.data` and then reconstruct the masked array with the original mask. However, I am writing an application which maps arbitrary functions from the user onto many different arrays, some of which are masked and some aren't, and I am looking to avoid a special handler just for masked arrays. Furthermore, these arrays have a distinction between MISSING, NaN, and Inf that is important so I can't just use an array with `np.nan`s instead of `masked` values.

---

Additionally, if anyone has any perspective on why this behavior exists I would like to know. It seems strange to have this in the same operation because the validity of results of an operation on unmasked values are really the responsibility of the user, who can choose to then "clean up" by using the `fix_invalid` function.

Furthermore, if anyone knows anything about the progress of missing values in numpy please share as the oldest [posts](http://www.numpy.org/NA-overview.html) are from 2011-2012 where there was a debate that never resulted in anything.

---

EDIT: 2017-10-30

To add to hpaulj's answer; the definition of the log function with a modified domain has side effects on the behavior of the log in the numpy namespace.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.log(np.ma.masked_array([-1,0,1,2],[1,0,0,0]))
/home/salotz/anaconda3/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  #!/home/salotz/anaconda3/bin/python
/home/salotz/anaconda3/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  #!/home/salotz/anaconda3/bin/python
Out[2]: 
masked_array(data = [-- -- 0.0 0.6931471805599453],
             mask = [ True  True False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)

In [3]: mylog = np.ma.core._MaskedUnaryOperation(np.core.umath.log)

In [4]: np.log(np.ma.masked_array([-1,0,1,2],[1,0,0,0]))
/home/salotz/anaconda3/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  #!/home/salotz/anaconda3/bin/python
/home/salotz/anaconda3/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  #!/home/salotz/anaconda3/bin/python
Out[4]: 
masked_array(data = [-- -inf 0.0 0.6931471805599453],
             mask = [ True False False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

`np.log` now has the same behavior as `mylog`, but `np.ma.log` is unchanged:

```
In [5]: np.ma.log(np.ma.masked_array([-1,0,1,2],[1,0,0,0]))
Out[5]: 
masked_array(data = [-- -- 0.0 0.6931471805599453],
             mask = [ True  True False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Is there a way to avoid this?

Using `Python 3.6.2 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)` and numpy `1.12.1`

Answer (score 5):

Just clarify what appears to be going on here

`np.ma.log` runs `np.log` on the argument, but it traps the Warnings:

```
In [26]: np.log([-1,0,1,2])
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
  #!/usr/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[26]: array([        nan,        -inf,  0.        ,  0.69314718])
```

It masks the `nan` and `-inf` values. And apparently copies the original values into these `data` slots:

```
In [27]: np.ma.log([-1,0,1,2])
Out[27]: 
masked_array(data = [-- -- 0.0 0.6931471805599453],
             mask = [ True  True False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
In [28]: _.data
Out[28]: array([-1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.69314718])
```

(running in Py3; numpy version 1.13.1)

This masking behavior is not unique to `ma.log`.  It is determined by its class

```
In [41]: type(np.ma.log)
Out[41]: numpy.ma.core._MaskedUnaryOperation
```

In `np.ma.core` it is defined with `fill` and `domain` attributes:

```
log = _MaskedUnaryOperation(umath.log, 1.0,
                        _DomainGreater(0.0))
```

So the valid domain (unmasked) is >0:

```
In [47]: np.ma.log.domain([-1,0,1,2])
Out[47]: array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

that domain mask is `or-ed` with

```
In [54]: ~np.isfinite(np.log([-1,0,1,2]))
...
Out[54]: array([ True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

which has the same values.

Looks like I could define a custom `log` that does not add its own domain masking:

```
In [58]: mylog = np.ma.core._MaskedUnaryOperation(np.core.umath.log)
In [59]: mylog([-1,0,1,2])
Out[59]: 
masked_array(data = [        nan        -inf  0.          0.69314718],
             mask = False,
       fill_value = 1e+20)

In [63]: np.ma.masked_array([-1,0,1,2],[1,0,0,0])
Out[63]: 
masked_array(data = [-- 0 1 2],
             mask = [ True False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
In [64]: np.ma.log(np.ma.masked_array([-1,0,1,2],[1,0,0,0]))
Out[64]: 
masked_array(data = [-- -- 0.0 0.6931471805599453],
             mask = [ True  True False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
In [65]: mylog(np.ma.masked_array([-1,0,1,2],[1,0,0,0]))
Out[65]: 
masked_array(data = [-- -inf 0.0 0.6931471805599453],
             mask = [ True False False False],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Comment: Learning a lot from this post, thanks. Honestly didn't think there would be a way around this. Also I didn't even notice that the example was using the `np.ma.log` function and I tested it with `np.log` but it has the same effect. Your definition of `mylog` has side effects though. I updated the question to show this and request a way to avoid this.